# Using special character to JOIN

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table A which loaded from a external stage, one column col1 has special char for example 'Español'. I need to join tableA with tableB

```
select * from tableA
join tableB
on tableA.col1 = tableB.col1
```

I know tableB.col1 has exactly same value 'Español', but this join couldn't catch it. Anyone knows why and how to get it joined?

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't such a thing as "a UTF-8 char". UTF-8 is a *system of rules for encoding* Unicode code points (which are *not* one-to-one with characters of text) as bytes. Every code point (and thus every character representable in Unicode text) can be encoded with this system.

Comment: Anyway, we definitely can't tell you anything with that little information. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . At the very least, we should see some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the join is failing it is because the values in `col1` are not equivalent even though they might look the same when displayed.  I wonder if using `hex_encode(col1)` on each table might surface the difference?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, and yes you are right!  They return different strings when I hex_encode them, although they look exactly same. Does it they consider as two different values so they cannot be joined? Or is there a way to join them?

Comment: Yes - trailing spaces or other hidden characters will not be considered equal as part of a join - `SELECT 'ABC' = 'ABC';` will return TRUE while `SELECT 'ABC' = 'ABC ';` will return FALSE.